# Degraded RAID1 array boots with one drive, not with the other

Tags: grub2, mdadm, lubuntu, raid1

## UPDATE

It seems `initramfs` fails to properly mount the array. If I stop and reassemble them, they works:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md124
mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md124 /dev/sda6
```

Maybe `initrd` tries to run the degraded array assembling sdb partitions only and stop. I don't know how to debug and/or fix it.

---

To test my brand new RAID1 array, I disconnected one of my hard disks (sda) and tried to boot the degraded system (I set BOOT_DEGRADED=true). All works as expected, the OS boots without problems and an email is sent by mdadm to inform me of the problem.

The story is different with the other disk. After the sync I tried to do the same thing disconnecting sdb. Grub starts the boot but the root partition is not mounted.

`/proc/mdadm` says the arrays exist but they are inactive. I tried to assemble them manually, but `mdadm` gives me the "Device or resource busy" error.

I run `grub-install --recheck` on both drives, but nothing changed. The UUID of sdaX and sdbX are the same, and all UUIDs are correct, I checked them with `blkid`.

Comment: did you found a solution for ?

Comment: @wnasich: try `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`